# Can US citizen apply for UK's standard visitor visa while being in UK?

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

The problem is very simple yet complicated as hell.

My girlfriend wants to visit to me in UK, but we are very confused about the visa things.

As far as we understand when she'll come to UK she'll be allowed to travel for three months just with her passport. But I need her to stay longer and the question is - is she gonna be able to apply for UK standard visa that is for six months while being in here in UK? Or she'll have to get back USA to apply for that visa?

Maybe somebody has done something similar and knows something about it...

Comment: I don't think that there is a UK embassy or UK Visa center in UK for obvious reasons. With that said, she would need to visit and apply for the visa in the USA.

Comment: @LampPost she normally wouldn't need a visa at all, but if she did, she could apply for it anywhere outside the UK, not just in the US.  Schengen consulates are allowed to accept applications only from those residing in their territory, but UK consulates do not have such a rule.

Comment: @phoog oh I overlooked that fact. thanks for the correction

Comment: An applicant for an entry clearance must be outside the United Kingdom and Islands at the time of the application.

Comment: And one more point to remember if longer stays happen quite frequently, she might have a thorough interrogation or maybe denied entry.

Comment: @phoog look at my answer. Seems to me that UK consulates **do**  have that rule.

Comment: @CMaster they have that rule for student visas, as you note, but not for visitor visas, which this question is about.

Comment: @phoog "any other application must be made to the post in the country or territory where the applicant is living" seems to say that all applications that are non student (or the exception in 28A, which is only for T5s) must be made in place of residence.

Comment: @CMaster see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47894/where-can-a-tourist-apply-for-a-uk-visitor-standard-visa?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually she can stay for up to 6 months visa-free, but this is decided by the border guard on arrival. The more documentation you provide supporting her reasons for visiting (and above all, her intention to go back), the more likely she'll be granted a 6-month stay.

Curious: why do you "need her to stay longer"? That's what I would ask myself if I was a UK border agent, and I would like to see documentation verifying it.

By the way, as far as I'm aware she'd Need to exit the country to get a visa if she first entered visa-free. One can change from a long-stay (eg. work, student) visa to another inside the UK, but not from visa-free status to a visa

Comment: In my experience visiting the UK as a US citizen (which I've not done in many years), I was invariably seeking entry for a few days, and was stamped in for six months on the basis of a brief explanation of my plans (for example, "visiting a friend in London").  Volunteering documentation could be counterproductive.

Comment: She's my gf, so you can understand why 'I need her to stay longer'...

Comment: @phoog I didn't say one should produce the papers upfront, but rather *be able* to if asked

Comment: @ArtursDerkintis be careful, though.  If she says when she enters that she's planning to stay for some number of months then she will be subjected to extra scrutiny.

Comment: "She is my gf and I need her to stay for longer" is exactly the sort of thing that will get her denied entry. If they think she is really trying to live with you under the pretense of visiting occasionally she will be turned around at the border.

Comment: phoog @crazydre Following this logic, let her say she is only having a transit flight, they might give her the nationality...

Comment: No, just no. US citizens are visa-exempt but only if they actually intend to visit for max 6 months and leave afterwards. The more and closer ties to the UK she Shows, the more likely border guards are going to suspect she's trying to live there (which requires some form of visa for all but EU/EFTA nationals and Commonwealth citizens with a right of abode sticker in their passport)

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis all I can tell you is that every time I visited the UK with a US passport, I stayed for less than a week and I got a 6-month admission stamp.

Comment: "One can change from one visa to another inside the UK, but not from visa-free status to a visa" This isn't correct for the Standard Visitor Visa. There are no switches allowed in either case and attempting to switch can get the person in trouble. Please read Paragraph 24 of the rules, or give permission for me to edit your answer.

Comment: @Crazydre, no she shouldn't lie, unless she is very, very confident in her ability to spin a consistent story. We've got loads of questions on here from Americans who would have been let in if they just told the truth, but tried to say what they thought the IO wanted to hear. If she's visiting for longer, and staying with her boyfriend, she should say that **if asked**. However the worrying part of the phrase is **"need"**. What  is the *need* (not *want*) for. The word implies activities not allowed as a visitor.

Comment: @GayotFow Edited

Comment: @CMaster I don't condone lying either, but it is a fact that claiming that her bf "Needs her to stay longer" is a sure means of getting refused entry, unless she's able to prove extremely convincing ties to the US forcing her to return home. I've observed cases of this myself

Comment: @Crazydre the point is that as soon as the IO spots an inconsistency, she'll get in trouble. So saying that she only plans to stay for one week isn't a good plan if that isn't the truth. Equally, saying "friend" over "boyfriend" causes a lot of rejections.

Comment: So let's say she's asked how Long she's staying for and for what purpose. If she then says "visit bf for 5 months" (for example), surely further interrogation is highly likely. Is there anything Special she should bring besides a return ticket, paychecks to prove employment in the US, the housing contract proving residence in the US, and receipts of US tax payments? Obviously she'd want to bring as much as possible to Show **if asked**

Comment: @Crazydre A contract to prove she has work to return to and anything from her employer showing a belief that she will be returning to them in five months are both going to help. Pay cheques merely show *prior* employment, not employment after the trip.

Comment: @ArtursDerkintis Please read this discussion, lots of useful info from Cmaster and gsnedders. Also CMaster's separate answer is spot-on

Comment: @Crazydre important edit, much better with that change, thanks

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not possible to apply for a visa (of pretty much any kind) for the UK, from within the UK. In fact, they must (under normal circumstances) apply from their country of residence - note that the UK frequently refers to visas as "entry clearance". [According the UK Immigration Rules, part 1:](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk)

> 28. An applicant for an entry clearance must be outside the United Kingdom and Islands at the time of the application. An applicant for an entry clearance who is seeking entry as a short-term student must apply to a post designated by the Secretary of State to accept applications for entry clearance for that purpose and from that category of applicant. Subject to paragraph 28A, any other application must be made to the post in the country or territory where the applicant is living which has been designated by the Secretary of State to accept applications for entry clearance for that purpose and from that category of applicant. Where there is no such post the applicant must apply to the appropriate designated post outside the country or territory where he is living.

However, your central premise is somewhat flawed. It isn't possible to extend visitor stays by getting a visa. Equally, the UK doesn't really differentiate between those who have a visa and those who don't need one - they are all, normally admitted for 6 months. So your girlfriend can remain for up to 6 months without a visa. However, the length of admitted stay is at the discretion of the Immigration Officer that admits her. See again, Immigration Rules part 1:

> 23A. A person who is not a visa national and who is seeking leave to enter on arrival in the United Kingdom for a period not exceeding 6 months for a purpose for which prior entry clearance is not required under these Rules may be granted such leave, for a period not exceeding 6 months.

It seems as if you and your girlfriend are not really familiar with the rules. You should probably become (at least passingly) so, especially with 
[Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) which describes the rules for visitors. The sections of interest to you are probably V1 and V4 (which describes who is eligible, and what you can and can't do). Note that V4.10 forbids you getting married unless you have a visa that is marked for this purpose.

Note that your girlfriend **may** be asked what she is doing, how long she intends to do it for, and how she intends to support herself in this time. She **may** be asked to provide evidence to support this. They may call you, to confirm that her story is correct and that you will house her. You should agree in advance how long she is staying. If she is not so wealthy that plane ticket costs are trivial, she should have a return flight ticket (can be refundable/changeable) so that they know she can still leave even if she overspends. Alternatively, she may get waved through after minimal questioning - *but you need to be prepared for the more thorough approach*.

Note that the phrasing of your question would ring alarm bells for immigration. You say (emphasis mine):

> But I **need** her to stay longer

There is nothing permitted under visitor rules, other than perhaps medical treatment that would count as **need** rather than **want**. Saying things to the IO like "But I **need** to stay for 4 months" will immediately set off alarm bells and further questioning.

Note: Your girlfriend shouldn't attempt to follow any "strategies" when talking to the IO, except telling truthful answers to their questions. If you search the tags [uk](/questions/tagged/uk) [us-citizens](/questions/tagged/us-citizens) together, you will find numerous examples of US citizens who were refused entry when trying to be clever, who would have been allowed in if they just both:

- Were honest/truthful
- Didn't volunteer extra information/ask for things that don't exist (eg a 3 month "visa" for a 2 week visa-free stay)

Related material

- [UK Immigration officers arrivals interview questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49231/uk-immigration-officers-arrivals-interview-questions/49237#49237)
- [Will US boyfriend have issue visiting me in UK for 3 months?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50059/will-us-boyfriend-have-issue-visiting-me-in-uk-for-3-months)

Comment: I think we can all agree that "I **Need** to stay for x months" or "my bf **Needs** me to stay for x months" isn't the best Thing to say. Better to say one **wishes** to stay for that long and provide documentation if asked

Comment: +1, despite not being accepted by the OP, this is the right answer to the question. The accepted answer is not totally wrong, but substantially inaccurate.

Comment: @GayotFow Totally agree, I personally think the asker should accept this answer rather than mine