# South African traveling form USA to the U.K

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, south-african-citizens

I'm currently an South African au pair in the USA and want to travel to the U.K. for a long weekend. Can I apply for a visa here in the USA or do I need to do it in South Africa ?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47894/where-can-a-tourist-apply-for-a-uk-visitor-standard-visa