# Can I apply for a UK visa from a country I am travelling through?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, applications

One of my Family member(Original country India) has valid Schengen visa(Visa Type : short term visa - Visit Family and friends) and she is already in Denmark. Now she wish to visit London. Does she Apply UK visa from Denmark?? Or only possibility is to apply it from India.

Please provide some useful link,that I can follow or contact for detail information.

Comment: Related question [Where can a tourist apply for a UK Visitor (standard) Visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47894/where-can-a-tourist-apply-for-a-uk-visitor-standard-visa/48429#48429)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply for a U.K. visa from any location, it does not need to be your home country. The process is here https://www.gov.uk/apply-standard-visitor-visa, a decision generally takes around 15 days. A guide to the supporting documents required is here https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

Comment: That might need to be "any location you have legal permission to be in".